# Creating a txt file using php in linux

Tags: php, linux, bash

We have few fields in the HTML page and this is being written into a file using php.

The file has the data, however, running a bash script which takes this file with a .txt as extension is not working.

When the file is opened and re-saved manually the bash script will work properly!

I've tried changing the permissions of the file but the bash script is still not using this file. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

PHP Script:

```
$name = "test.txt";    
$handle = fopen($name, "w");    
fwrite($handle, "my message");    
fclose($handle);
```

Bash Script:

```
INPUT="$1"

OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,

[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }

while read message number ; do 

    echo $message # or whaterver you want to do with the $line variable

    #j=$[$(line)]

    echo $number

    echo "$message" | gnokii --sendsms $number --smsc $SMSC

done < $INPUT

IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Comment: Can you post what the bash script is trying to do? Also, clarify what you mean by "just the extension is renamed"?

Comment: Can you try: `$name = "/tmp/test.txt";`

Comment: I am rolling back your question, because if you change `unlink` to `fclose`, it is a completely different question.

Comment: sorry it was fclose only. i pasted it wrong. unlink was commented.

Comment: @rlvamsi Had you posted your full code... (`dot-dot-dot`) in the first place ;-)

Comment: This is the basic code needed.if i get through this problem i can add more to it.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use `fclose($handle)` rather than `unlink()`

**Edit** OK then, "Because..."

1. `fclose($handle)` closes the file referenced by the handle: `$handle`
2. `unlink()` takes a file path string as a parameter, rather than a resource.
3. If used as intended, `unlink()` will actually delete the file.

Comment: An explanation would be nice... "Because... "

Comment: @TheGunner, unlink() takes a resource as it's *second* parameter as well.

Answer (score 0):

`unlink()` as mentioned would delete the file. Just created a plain script like this

```
<?php
$name = "/var/www/test.txt";    
$handle = fopen($name, "w");    
fwrite($handle, "test,9944");    
fclose($handle);
?>
```

This script works f9 with storing the data. But running bash script on this with the file input as test.txt does nothing. But again opening and saving with the same file name and it works.

Answer (score 0):

finally got the answer its the end of file that is missing in text file that is created by php. anyway thank you all for contributing.